# Getting reference not found error in ajax in JSF-ADF Faces

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2, oracle-adf

I can't figure out the problem. In listener part of ajax, it gives me the listener reference not found. I don't know what I am doing wrong. I'm working on Oracle JDeveloper IDE. Here is my code.

Here is part of my JSF page:

```
<af:menuBar id="menuBar">
    <af:menu text="Add" id="m1">
        <af:commandMenuItem text="Text Box" id="addTextBox" >
            <f:ajax event="click" render="msg" listener="#{addItem.start}"/>
        </af:commandMenuItem>
    </af:menu>
    <af:menu text="Contact" id="m2"/>
</af:menuBar>
<af:message id="msg" message="#{addItem.text}" >
```

Here is my AddItems.java file:

```
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.event.AjaxBehaviorEvent;

@ManagedBean(name="addItem")
public class AddItems {

    public AddItems() {
    }

    String text = "first";

    public void start(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) throws javax.faces.event.AbortProcessingException {
        setText("changed");
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }
}
```

Comment: Help us help you. Tell us what you are trying to do and *version* of JDev/ADF.

Comment: I'm trying to change the message when the commandMenuItem clicked. My version of JDeveloper is 11g r2

Comment: if you're trying to call a method on the backing java bean, why not use ActionListener property? Why add a non-adf component: f:ajax?

Comment: Yes you're right. I didn't know that. But actually almost 10 hours ago I did it. Thanks for your comment.